# use of article in a sentence

Tags: articles

Is it really necessary to place an article like 'a, an or the' even if the sentence makes perfect sense without it.

Eg.

We have linked molecular properties to macroscopic properties for a simple system.

or

We have linked the molecular properties to the macroscopic properties for a simple system.

Comment: Each of your sentences is fine.

Comment: Though note that the meanings are subtly different.  The first implies a more general "linkage", while the second implies that the linkage may be only in specific cases/examples.

Comment: The articles "a" and "an" are only used with singular nouns. The noun phrases "molecular properties" and "macroscopic properties" in your sentence are plural, so they cannot be used with "a" or "an": they can only be used with "the", or with no article. The use of no article (also called the "zero article") in English follows specific rules: you cannot just leave out an article because the sentence "makes sense" without it. But in this case, the "zero article" is allowed by the rules.